# Printing at specific paper position from JAVA ui

Tags: java, printing

I already have a ui that collects all the information I need to print over a Pre-printed paper (invoices). And I need to print collected informacion in specific places of the paper. So far I've been generating from the program, an excel file that is used for this purpose. I would like to know if there is a way to avoid the excel file, and print directly from the ui.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Yes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/).

Comment: Are you using `swing` ?

Comment: Yes, I am using Swing. I will look up for drawString. Do You know what the positions (x,y) are measured in? cm, mm?